# Is there a Win32 API yet for Windows 10 v1809 Sets?

Tags: windows-10, .net-4.5, winforms-interop

The next release of Windows 10 adds a new UI feature which, best as I can understand, is tabbed windowing with the twist that tabs can come from different applications. Or, put another way, it’s a modern take at Binder:

[image: Microsoft Office Binder]
<sub>(source: [jdstiles.com](http://jdstiles.com/mso2k/binder/msbinder.gif))</sub>

[Recent builds have started some limited support for Win32 apps:](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17643-for-skip-ahead/#w5H0kZoLwSZZUUg3.97)

> Sets is now enabled for most desktop (Win32) apps that use a default and non-customized title bar. Apps that customize their title bar will not have Sets (e.g. Paint.exe).

Suppose I *do* customize my title bar — is there an API yet that helps me integrate my app with this?

Comment: RS5/1809 is in an very early development phase, so wait until Microsoft finished the feature and documented it in the SDK.

Comment: **SetWindowStyle(hwndDlg, WS_POPUP, 0);** should be enoug according to [this commit in ProcessHacker](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/commit/175749685f6b20e1de3c940571ce907c57cecccb)

Comment: Or you could just stop customizing your title bar when running on a Sets-enabled system. The user won't see your custom title bar anyway because the title bar is now a tab.

Comment: That’s the idea, really — switch to a regular title bar while I’m a tab. I presume that’s rightly what Office does.